# Rails app doesn't serve JS and SCSS assets in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, production, precompile

First of all everything works fine in development enviroment. 
But if I switch to production environment my Rails App doesn't serve JS and CSS assets.

I deployed assets to public directory:

```
 rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

with no errors.

The Log says:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/custom-9f5239947caa407b080981084efbe1b998006e083c7c79e950376483e1ac0f27.css"):
```

and

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-5e67105cb72dda5c0d9dcc451a325501380be971c097076180211f3e90a99ba3.js"):
```

assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( cocoon.js )
```

production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :debug
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'minitest'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'rack'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'thin'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.23.0'
gem 'faker'
gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'master' # For 4.x
gem 'simple_hashtag'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'cocoon', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.6'
```

Comment: Can you give us any details about your production env? Is it Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in production.rb I changed      `config.assets.compile` from false to true:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Yes, this is the easy way to solve, but it's not recommended as the assets will be compiled every time they are needed. This can cause some timeouts for the user. You can check if you have set, in production, the env var of `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` as the default setting is `config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css ) # Because Asset Pipeline by default only compress application.(css|js)
```

And this:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
```

I hope that works for you :D

Comment: I, [2015-11-13T16:11:55.503532 #5116]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/custom-9f5239947caa407b080981084efbe1b998006e083c7c79e950376483e1ac0f27.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-13 16:11:55 +0100
F, [2015-11-13T16:11:55.505532 #5116] FATAL -- : 
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/custom-9f5239947caa407b080981084efbe1b998006e083c7c79e950376483e1ac0f27.css"):

Comment: Aditionally, put that on your config/application.rb:

`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`